# Nautilus copy and paste (clipboard) causes pasted target application to freeze

Tags: 20.04, nautilus, wayland

Whenever I copy content with the Ubuntu file explorer Nautilus, like a filename string, and try to paste the filename into other applications, like chrome, it will cause the target application to freeze until I copy something somewhere else.

I'm running wayland on Ubuntu 20.04, and this only happens in Nautilus.

Is there any way to  fix this?

Comment: Not sure if related, but the same thing happens to me on 20.04 when copying any text from gedit and pasting to another application.

Comment: @Oscar This acutally happens in several other gtk apps too, kind of an annoy issue.